# On local cohomology and canonical module

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay, local-cohomology

I'm studying local cohomology and the canonical module of a local Cohen-Macaulay ring $R$ is very important due to local duality and its consequences (as non-vanishing of $d$-th local cohomology of an $R$-module $M$ where $d=\dim(M)$).

The canonical module can be defined as a finitely generated $R$-module whose Matlis dual is isomorphic to $d$-th local cohomology of $R$ where $d=\dim(R)$. (Some books call it dualizing module.) I know that such a module is unique (up to isomorphism), maximal Cohen-Macaulay of type $1$ and of finite injective dimension. I also know that the converse holds.

On the other hand, how to proceed if $R$ does not admit a canonical module? Are many results lost on about local cohomology? Also I would like to see some example of Cohen-Macaulay ring without canonical module. Having in mind that a Cohen-Macaulay ring admits a canonical module if, and only if, its an epimorphic image of a Gorenstein ring, I tried to get one, but I couldn't.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: To construct a Cohen-Macaulay ring without a canonical module is not an easy task. It seems that such an example can be found in the paper "Fibres formelles d'un anneau local noethérien" by Ferrand and Raynaud.

Comment: @user26857  Bruns-Herzog book refers to this paper for an example, but it is too obscure to me. I was hoping for a simpler one.

Comment: In this theory, one needs to pass to the completion first or else Matlis duality is not a true duality. In fact, the Matlis dual of the $d$th local homology of $R$ produces not the canonical module of $R$, which may not exist, but of it's completion, which necessarily does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the example 6.1 of the following paper:

"A few examples of local rings I", Jun-ichi Nishimura.

Comment: Thank you so much!